# Georeference Suomi-NPP NRT HDF to GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, hdf, nasa

I am trying to georeference Suomi-NPP VNP09_NRT (Near Real Time) data that is in HDF format ([example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMVwi7a-Wfarg5xYjkEwLxBOAEKj51gj/view?usp=share_link)) to GeoTIFF using only GDAL.

Currently, this is my code:

```
def georeference_array(array, string_projection, bounding_coordinates):
    # Create a GDAL driver
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    
    # Get the array dimensions
    height, width = array.shape

    # Create an empty GDAL dataset to store the array data
    dataset = driver.Create("test.tif", width, height, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

    # Write the array data to the dataset
    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)

    # Set the projection information using the provided string_projection
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromWkt(string_projection)
    dataset.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

    # Set the geotransform (bounding coordinates)
    left, top, right, bottom = bounding_coordinates
    pixel_width = (right - left) / width
    pixel_height = (bottom - top) / height
    dataset.SetGeoTransform((left, pixel_width, 0, top, 0, pixel_height))
    dataset=None

georeference_array(band_array, crs, [west_bound, north_bound, east_bound, south_bound])
```

**band_array** is one of the HDF bands using *ReadAsArray*.

**crs** is provided by NASA:

```
crs = 'PROJCS["unnamed",\
       GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid", \
       DATUM["Not specified (based on custom spheroid)", \
       SPHEROID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0]], \
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],\
       UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],\
       PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"], \
       PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0], \
       PARAMETER["false_easting",0], \
       PARAMETER["false_northing",0], \
       UNIT["Meter",1]]'
```

The bounds are retrieved using *gdal.Info*.

I don't understand why it is not well georeferenced when I open the GeoTIFF in QGIS.

I also tried this [tutorial](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/resources/e-learning/working-daily-nasa-viirs-surface-reflectance-data/#section3) with no success, I think I am using the wrong bound coordinates...

Also, HEG NASA software doesn't seem to work with this product.

**Update 2023/07/31**

So, I decided to change the code and not use the sinusoidal projection:

```
north_bound = in_product_global_metadata["NorthBoundingCoord"]
west_bound = in_product_global_metadata["WestBoundingCoord"]
south_bound = in_product_global_metadata["SouthBoundingCoord"]
east_bound = in_product_global_metadata["EastBoundingCoord"]

x_res = (east_bound-west_bound)/n_col
y_res = (north_bound-south_bound)/n_row
geo_info = (west_bound, x_res, 0, north_bound, 0, -y_res)
                                                                                               
output_path = os.path.join("results", product_name+".tif") 
dataType = gdal_array.NumericTypeCodeToGDALTypeCode(rgb.dtype) 
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')   
out_file = driver.Create(output_path, n_col, n_row, 3, dataType, options=["PHOTOMETRIC=RGB", "PROFILE=GeoTIFF"])    

for band in range(rgb.shape[2]):                                                     
    out_file.GetRasterBand(band+1).WriteArray(rgb[:,:,band])                           
    out_file.GetRasterBand(band+1).SetNoDataValue(0)                                
out_file.GetRasterBand(1).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)            
out_file.GetRasterBand(2).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_GreenBand)             
out_file.GetRasterBand(3).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_BlueBand)           
out_file.SetGeoTransform(geo_info)                                                      
out_file.SetProjection("EPSG:4326")                                                          
outF_file = None
```

I still have two problems:

- Image is flipped;
- There are some horizontal data gaps (I think this is part of the instrument).

[image]

Comment: @user2856 , just added to the post, click on "example". Thank you.

Comment: @user2856 sorry, something went wrong when I uploaded the file. I updated the link. Also, I added a NASA tutorial, but for product VNP09GA.001. I tried to follow, but I don't know where to find UpperLeftPointMtrs inside VNP09_NRT.

Comment: Thanks for re-uploading. The tutorial you link to is for a different product, the daily VNP09GA (non near real-time) which is delivered in a different format (HDF5 / HDF-EOS5) and isn't applicable to the near real-time VNP09_NRT.001 product which is delivered in HDF4 / HDF-EOS format.  I haven't been able to georeference the VNP09 NRT data, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, I know it is for a different product, but some of the steps are similar. I opened the NRT product using GDAL, pyhdf.SD also works.

Comment: @user2856 I changed my code and only used EPSG4326, maybe now it can help a bit more